# JCodeModel: Attributes and Lists with special class-types

Tags: jcodemodel

I started to work with the JCodeModel today.
I want to add Attributes with other types than int, String, boolean etc. to my JDefinedClass. The final Java Code built by the JCodeModel should look like:

```
public Class Team {
    private int teamID;
    private String teamName;
    private Coach coach;
}
```

How can I add the Field coach with the class type "Coach" with the JCodeModel?

```
jClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, *???*, coach);
```

The second question is:
How do I add e.g.

```
ArrayList<Coach> coachList;
```

to my attribute List?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply generate the `Coach` class, and pass it as a parameter to the `field(...)` method. Note that this method accepts a `JType` as the second parameter, and `JClass` as well as `JDefinedClass` are both inheriting from `JType`.

For the `ArrayList`, you can define the type parameter by calling `narrow` on the defined class, passing in another `JType`. (This even works for type parameters - that is, you can even call `c.narrow(cm.ref("T"))` to give it a type parameter called `T`).

Here is an example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.sun.codemodel.JClass;
import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;
import com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;


public class CodeModelTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();


        JDefinedClass teamClass = codeModel._class("Team");
        JDefinedClass coachClass = codeModel._class("Coach");
        teamClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, coachClass, "coach");

        JClass arrayListClass = codeModel.ref(ArrayList.class);
        JClass arrayListOfCoachClass = arrayListClass.narrow(coachClass);
        teamClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, arrayListOfCoachClass, "coaches");

        codeModel.build(new File("."));
    }

}
```

It generates the (empty) class `Coach`, and the class `Team` as

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Team {

    private Coach coach;
    private ArrayList<Coach> coaches;

}
```

(I hope this answer is sufficient. And although the links might die in the future: I found these tutorials very helpful to get a first grip on the CodeModel <sub>Edit: Links updated, see below</sub> : [CodeModel Basics](https://web.archive.org/web/20150414122839/http://blogtech.cardosi.net/2013/03/19/tutorial-java-codemodel-basics/), [CodeModel Inheritance](http://web.archive.org/web/20150516142029/http://blogtech.cardosi.net/2013/12/18/tutorial-java-code-generation-codemodel-inheritance/))

---

**EDIT:** Indeed, the links died. They should only be considered as "supplemental", or as a pointer for further reading. The main information (regarding the original question) should be contained in this answer. I don't have a recommendation for other tutorials (except for what everybody may find with basic websearches), but for now, I replaced the links with their latest snapshots from the web archive.

Comment: The links do not work anymore. Any replacement you suggest?

Comment: @iCrus I don't have a specific suggestion for now, see the **EDIT**, but have updated the links with their latest snapshot from the web archive. When I find a good tutorial for the JCodeModel, I might update the links again, but in any case, the code snippets that I posted should still sufficiently answer the original question.